# Creating closures in match arms

Tags: types, rust, pattern-matching, closures, boxing

I'm going through the Rust Book and have been adapting the "minigrep" project such that instead of having both `search` and `search_case_insensitive` functions, I have a single `search` function that takes an enum specifying the case sensitivity. This is what I have that works:

```
pub fn search<'a>(query: &str, contents: &'a str, case: &Case) -> Vec<&'a str> {
    match case {
        Case::Sensitive => contents
            .lines()
            .filter(|line| line.contains(query))
            .collect(),

        Case::Insensitive => {
            let query = query.to_lowercase();

            contents
                .lines()
                .filter(|line| line.to_lowercase().contains(&query))
                .collect()
        }
    }
}
```

I thought I'd try to rewrite this, to remove the duplicated logic, using closures. However, that's causing all kinds of type-checking problems. My first attempt:

```
let query_lower = query.to_lowercase();

let filter = match case {
   Case::Sensitive => |line| line.contains(query),
   Case::Insensitive => |line| line.to_lowercase().contains(&query_lower)
};
```

I quickly learned that different closures have different types, even if they have the same signature. I read that boxing the closure might help:

```
let filter: Box<dyn Fn(&str) -> bool> = match case {
    Case::Sensitive => Box::new(|line| line.contains(query)),
    Case::Insensitive => Box::new(|line| line.to_lowercase().contains(&query_lower))
};
```

That certainly solved the `match` having mismatched arm types, but now `.filter` is complaining that its parameter is the incorrect type and now I'm in over my head:

```
error[E0277]: expected a `FnMut<(&&str,)>` closure, found `dyn for<'r> Fn(&'r str) -> bool`
  --> src/lib.rs:27:17
   |
27 |         .filter(filter)
   |                 ^^^^^^ expected an `FnMut<(&&str,)>` closure, found `dyn for<'r> Fn(&'r str) -> bool`
   |
   = help: the trait `FnMut<(&&str,)>` is not implemented for `dyn for<'r> Fn(&'r str) -> bool`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `for<'r> FnMut<(&'r &str,)>` for `Box<dyn for<'r> Fn(&'r str) -> bool>`
```

Is it not a good idea to use closures in this way, because of the type discipline, or have I just "boxed" things incorrectly out of naivety?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `filter` closure's type has to be `FnMut(&Self::Item) -> bool` and since you have an `Iterator<Item = &str>` the `&Self::Item` becomes `&&str`. So instead of `Box<dyn Fn(&str) -> bool>` you should use `Box<dyn Fn(&&str) -> bool`:

```rust
enum Case {
    Sensitive,
    Insensitive,
}

fn search<'a>(query: &str, contents: &'a str, case: &Case) -> Vec<&'a str> {
    let query_lower = query.to_lowercase();

    let filter: Box<dyn Fn(&&str) -> bool> = match case {
        Case::Sensitive => Box::new(|line| line.contains(query)),
        Case::Insensitive => Box::new(|line| line.to_lowercase().contains(&query_lower)),
    };

    contents.lines().filter(filter).collect()
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7124ec1eedef7e09796aa9345f86f489)

This works because all `Fn` types are also `FnMut`.

Answer (score 2):

You were quite close. The error is the result of `Iterator::filter()` passing the *reference* to the element provided by iterator, so if you're iterating over `&str`, the closure passed to `filter` must accept `&&str`. Just changing `Box<dyn Fn(&str) -> bool>` to `Box<dyn Fn(&&str) -> bool>` fixes the example to compile.

You can avoid the unnecessary allocation by using two variables and a dynamic reference:

```
let case_sensitive_filter = |line: &&str| line.contains(query);
let case_insensitive_filter = |line: &&str| line.to_lowercase().contains(&query.to_lowercase());
let filter: &dyn Fn(&&str) -> bool = match case {
    Case::Sensitive => &case_sensitive_filter,
    Case::Insensitive => &case_insensitive_filter,
};
contents.lines().filter(filter).collect()
```

Another way to fix the incompatible arms issue is to create a single closure and check the case inside the closure:

```
let filter = |line: &&str| match case {
    Case::Sensitive => line.contains(query),
    Case::Insensitive => line.to_lowercase().contains(&query_lower),
};
```